OSS Unity Catalog - Failed to read delta table
A delta folder with sample data is created by the delta lake python package. Duckdb can read it properly:
./duckdb -c "select * from delta_scan('data2/datadelta')"
┌───────┬─────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│  id   │  name   │           dob            │
│ int64 │ varchar │ timestamp with time zone │
├───────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│     1 │ john    │ 2023-12-31 18:00:00-06   │
│     2 │ jane    │ 2024-02-01 18:00:00-06   │
│     3 │ jill    │ 2024-03-02 18:00:00-06   │
│     4 │ jack    │ 2024-04-03 19:00:00-05   │
└───────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────┘

Open source unity catalog can register the table but is unable to query it.
bin/uc table create --full_name unity.default.data --storage_location "/home/user1/work/unitycatalog/data2/datadelta" --columns "id INT, name STRING, dob DATE" --format DELTA 

It throws the following error:
bin/uc table read --full_name unity.default.data
Error occurred while executing the command. Failed to read delta table file:///home/user1/work/unitycatalog/data2/datadelta/Failed to read delta table


This is most likely happening because of some datatype mismatch issue.
The dob column has the datatype timestamp with time zone which is usually defined as TIMESTAMP whereas you are trying to use DATE which represents values comprising values of fields year, month and day, without a time-zone.
Ideally, it should have worked as explained here and here.
But there seems to be some other underlying issue here.

A delta folder with sample data is created by deltalake python package.

Could you please update your question to include the code related to this part as well for better reproducibility?
To further investigate this issue it would be helpful to know the datatype you are using and the method you are using to handle the timezone, if any.
